# Hover is not working in selenium test for Windows 8.1 and Firefox 60.4 combination

Tags: selenium, firefox, windows-8.1

Hover is not working in selenium test for Windows 8.1 and Firefox 60.4 combination code is right its working fine with linux OS with same firefox version

I have tried it with Linux with same firefox version

```
System info: host: 'PWDCSV-W81N14', ip: '10.232.247.174', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 60.4.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 11060, moz:profile: C:\Temp\rust_mozprofileHY1rIp, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 6.3, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
```

this is the error logs

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for com.ptc.selenium.SolventSelenium$9@67b174b9 (tried for 180 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)with build info as above
```

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for com.ptc.selenium.SolventSelenium$9@67b174b9 (tried for 180 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)with build info as above

Comment: can you share the code?